# unidirectinal @OneToMany without join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate. My parent class is company. Company has many activities. I need to load activities when company is loading. But I need to save company and the activities separately. Then in my company class I have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Activity.class)
private Set<Activity> activityReuslts;
```

In Activity I do not have any join to Company table. but when I try to run this it gives

```
'ORA-00972: identifier is too long' exception.
```

Can't I do this? I greatly appreciate your help.

I think when i use target entity it gives this exception since it is wrong mapping.

```
select this_.COMPANY_ID as y0_, this_.A
TTEMPT_ID as y1_ from MEL_COMPANY this_ 
inner join MEL_COMPANY_MEL_COMPANY_ACTIV
ITY_OUT_PUT activityre3_ on this_.COMPANY_ID=activityre3_.MEL_COMPANY_COMPANY_ID
and this_.ATTEMPT_ID=activityre3_.MEL_COMPANY_ATTEMPT_ID 

inner join MEL_COMPANY_ACTIVITY_OUT_PUT activityre1_ 
on activityre3_.activityReuslts_COMPANY_ACTIVITY_RE
SULT_ID=activityre1_.COMPANY_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ID.
```

According to this there are two joins for the same activityResults. 
one is wrong. 'MEL_COMPANY_MEL_COMPANY_ACTIVITY_OUT_PUT'

Comment: Please provide full stack-trace along with the table structure and your entity class (specially id and foreign key fields).

Comment: I think when i use target entity it gives this exception since it is wrong mapping.

Comment: 1. You didn't add what I asked 2. Format your question properly.